# LM2596: input voltage varies with output voltage?

Tags: solar-cell, buck, solar-energy

I have a 12V solar panel connected to a LM2596 (the one that has one pot for changing output voltage) that gives me a nice 5V output. However, when I check the voltage at the **input pins**, the voltage from the solar panel is also 5V. If I vary the voltage using the pot on the board, the input and output voltage is always the same. If I disconnect the LM2596, the voltage from the solar panel is back at 12V.

Why is this? I would expect the voltage at the input pins to be 12V, regardless of output voltage.

Comment: Is there load on thw output of the LM2596 and if yes, what kind of?

Comment: The solar panel can obviously not maintain the voltage with the load of the LM2596 module and whatever you connected as a load at the output of the LM2596 module connected to it. The solar panel will **never** deliver a steady 12 V as the voltage depends on the **current** it must deliver and obviously how much **light** the panel receives. Also you should supply more information: the maximum power of the solar panel, what load you have at 5 V.

Comment: The LM2596 is a single chip. It does not have a pot on it. So I guess you are using a module. Can you please provide full details about what module you are using? Please edit the question, rather than adding a comment. Also, please provide more detail about the solar panel. What is the rated Isc and Voc? Finally, during any experiments, please put the panel in full bright sun (or if not, then tell us) and please tell us what load is attached to the voltage controller output. Without all of this information we can only guess.

Comment: If the solar panel has an OC voltage of say 16V and a SC current rating of 10A in your sunshine, then the input voltage will remain a little below 16V (call it 12V) regardless of the output voltage, for loads up to several amps. But that's about a 120W panel. What are you using? And is it in full sunlight? My guess is your solar panel is underpowered for your load, as the other comments are hinting. Start with a load current about 1/10 the Isc YOU measure for your panel - if that works (Vin >=12V) increase load in steps and watch what happens.